# Python: Intersection over Union

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following question. I try to calculate the Intersection over Union, which is the overlap of two components divided by the unioin of two components.  Lets assume component1 is a matrix with ones where the first object is and component2 is a matrix with ones where the second object is. The Overlap i can caluclate with `np.logical_and(component == 1, component2 == 1)`. But how can I caclulate the Union? Im only interested in objects which are connected.

```
import numpy as np
component1 = np.array([[0,1,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,1]])
component2 = np.array([[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0]])
overlap = np.logical_and(component == 1, component2 == 1)
union = ?
IOU = len(overlap)/len(union)
```

Comment: What's your desired input from inputs in your post?

Comment: Do you mean my desired output ? This would be : IOU = overlap/union

Comment: sorry yes, desired output..not clear what you want at the end of all this.

Comment: I want the scoure or Number which is the  number of overlap points dived thorugh the number of unioin points. With that score I do postprocessing calculation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're only dealing with `0` and `1`, it's easier to work with boolean arrays:

```
import numpy as np
component1 = np.array([[0,1,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,1]], dtype=bool)
component2 = np.array([[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0]], dtype=bool)

overlap = component1*component2 # Logical AND
union = component1 + component2 # Logical OR

IOU = overlap.sum()/float(union.sum()) # Treats "True" as 1,
                                       # sums number of Trues
                                       # in overlap and union
                                       # and divides

>>> 1*overlap
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
>>> 1*union
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
>>> IOU
0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: Ahh, to treat the array as boolean was the trick, thank you very much!

Comment: I would use np.count_nonzero here instead of sum as it is wayy faster

Answer (score 1):

**Oleksii** has an answer for your question in [medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/intersection-over-union-iou-calculation-for-evaluating-an-image-segmentation-model-8b22e2e84686).

Simply put:

```
intersection = numpy.logical_and(result1, result2)

union = numpy.logical_or(result1, result2)

iou_score = numpy.sum(intersection) / numpy.sum(union)

print(‘IoU is %s’ % iou_score)
```

Also, he gives a very good explains of it. Take a look at the above link.

Answer (score 1):

just use dedicated numpy functions `intersect1d` and `union1d`:

```
intersection = np.intersect1d(a, b)
union = np.union1d(a, b)
iou = intersection.shape[0] / union.shape[0]
```