# Calculating the Intersection of two polygons in a unit circle

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, geometry

Given a unit circle and two polygons inscribed, how can I go about calculating the Intersection over Union(IoU) of the two polygons?

Assume I have a Numpy array of the polygon coordinates with respect to the unit circle as:

```
Polygon 1: [
        (-0.708, 0.707),
        (0.309, -0.951),
        (0.587, -0.809),
    ]  

Polygon 2: [
        (1, 0),
        (0, 1),
        (-1, 0),
        (0, -1),
        (0.708, -0.708),
    ]
```

The expected IoU output should be:  0.124

Comment: I don't think you can do this for arbitrary polygons simply using numpy only. You could do it for rectangles, but arbitrary polygons will require [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Intersection over Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338166/python-intersection-over-union)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A simple algorithm for polygon intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection)

Comment: @Chicodelarose--isn't that a special case of polygons with 1's and 0's?

Comment: @CrisLuengo--link doesn't provide Python code but rather references to possible approaches and non-python packages.

Comment: @Chicodelarose: this is actually for matrices, not polygons

Comment: @DarrylG It gives pointers for how to implement polygon intersection. OP asks how to compute polygon intersection using only NumPy. The answer is to implement one of those algorithms. I don't think anyone is stupid enough to write such an implementation from scratch for an answer in SO, the best possible answer to this question is the one I linked. Your approach below is clever (+1), but it's just an approximation.

Comment: @RaffleBuffle-thought you had a great answer (which I based my answer upon).  Any reason why you deleted your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three Approaches

- Shapely
- Redo RaffleBuffle approach in Python rather than Java (check his/her post for description)
- Monte Carlo Simulation

**Shapely**

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p1 = [  (-0.708, 0.707),
        (0.309, -0.951),
        (0.587, -0.809)]  

p2 = [  (1, 0),
        (0, 1),
        (-1, 0),
        (0, -1),
        (0.708, -0.708)]

# Create polygons from coordinates
poly1 = Polygon(p1)
poly2 = Polygon(p2)

# ratio of intersection area to union area
print(poly1.intersection(poly2).area/poly1.union(poly2).area)
# Output: 0.12403616470027264
```

**RaffleBuffle Approach in Python**

```
import math
import numpy as np

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, id = None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.id = id
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None
        
    def __repr__(self):
        result = f"{self.x} {self.y} {self.id}"
        result += f" Prev: {self.prev.x} {self.prev.y} {self.prev.id}" if self.prev else ""
        result += f" Next: {self.next.x} {self.next.y} {self.next.id}" if self.next else ""
        return result
        
class Poly:
    def __init__(self, pts):
        self.pts = [p for p in pts]
        
        ' Sort polynomial coordinates based upon angle and radius in clockwize direction'
        # Origin is the centroid of points
        origin = Point(*[sum(pt.x for pt in self.pts)/len(self.pts), sum(pt.y for pt in self.pts)/len(self.pts)])

        # Sort points by incresing angle around centroid based upon angle and distance to centroid
        self.pts.sort(key=lambda p: clockwiseangle_and_distance(p, origin))
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        ' Overload for adding two polynomials '
        return Poly(self.pts + other.pts)
        
    def assign_chain(self):
        ' Assign prev and next '
        n = len(self.pts)
        for i in range(n):
            self.pts[i].next = self.pts[ (i + 1) % n]
            self.pts[i].prev = self.pts[(i -1) % n]
        return self
            
    def area(self):
        '''
            area enclosed by polynomial coordinates '
        
            Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates
        '''
        x = np.array([p.x for p in self.pts])
        y = np.array([p.y for p in self.pts])
        return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))
        
    def intersection(self):
        ' Intersection of coordinates with different ids '
        pts = self.pts
        
        n = len(pts)

        intersections = []
        for i in range(n):
            j = (i -1) % n
            if pts[j].id != pts[i].id:
                get_j = [pts[j], pts[j].next]
                get_i = [pts[i].prev, pts[i]]
                pt_intersect = line_intersect(get_j, get_i)
                if pt_intersect:
                    intersections.append(pt_intersect)
                
        return intersections
        
            
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(pt) for pt in self.pts)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(pt) for pt in self.pts)
    
def clockwiseangle_and_distance(point, origin):
    # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855695/sorting-list-of-two-dimensional-coordinates-by-clockwise-angle-using-python
    # Vector between point and the origin: v = p - o
    vector = [point.x-origin.x, point.y-origin.y]
    refvec = [0, 1]
    
    # Length of vector: ||v||
    lenvector = math.hypot(vector[0], vector[1])
    # If length is zero there is no angle
    if lenvector == 0:
        return -math.pi, 0
    # Normalize vector: v/||v||
    normalized = [vector[0]/lenvector, vector[1]/lenvector]
    dotprod  = normalized[0]*refvec[0] + normalized[1]*refvec[1]     # x1*x2 + y1*y2
    diffprod = refvec[1]*normalized[0] - refvec[0]*normalized[1]     # x1*y2 - y1*x2
    angle = math.atan2(diffprod, dotprod)
    # Negative angles represent counter-clockwise angles so we need to subtract them 
    # from 2*pi (360 degrees)
    if angle < 0:
        return 2*math.pi+angle, lenvector
    # I return first the angle because that's the primary sorting criterium
    # but if two vectors have the same angle then the shorter distance should come first.
    return angle, lenvector

def line_intersect(segment1, segment2):
    """ returns a (x, y) tuple or None if there is no intersection 
    
        segment1 and segment2 are two line segements
        
        specified by their starting/ending points
        
        Source: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_the_intersection_of_two_lines#Python
        
    """
    Ax1, Ay1 = segment1[0].x, segment1[0].y     # starting point in line segment 1
    Ax2, Ay2 = segment1[1].x, segment1[1].y     # ending point in line segment 1
    Bx1, By1 = segment2[0].x, segment2[0].y     # starting point in line segment 2
    Bx2, By2 = segment2[1].x, segment2[1].y     # ending point in line segment 2
    
    d = (By2 - By1) * (Ax2 - Ax1) - (Bx2 - Bx1) * (Ay2 - Ay1)
    
    if d:
        uA = ((Bx2 - Bx1) * (Ay1 - By1) - (By2 - By1) * (Ax1 - Bx1)) / d
        uB = ((Ax2 - Ax1) * (Ay1 - By1) - (Ay2 - Ay1) * (Ax1 - Bx1)) / d
    else:
        return
    if not(0 <= uA <= 1 and 0 <= uB <= 1):
        return
    x = Ax1 + uA * (Ax2 - Ax1)
    y = Ay1 + uA * (Ay2 - Ay1)
 
    return Point(x, y, None)

    
def polygon_iou(coords1, coords2):
    '''
        Calculates IoU of two 2D polygons based upon coordinates
    '''
    # Make polynomials ordered clockwise and assign ID (0 and 1)
    poly1 = Poly(Point(*p, 0) for p in coords1)   # counter clockwise with ID 0
    poly2 = Poly(Point(*p, 1) for p in coords2)   # counter clockwise with ID 1
    
    # Assign previous and next coordinates in polynomial chain
    poly1.assign_chain()
    poly2.assign_chain()
    
    # Polygon areas
    area1 = poly1.area()
    area2 = poly2.area()
            
    # Combine both polygons into one counter clockwise
    poly = poly1 + poly2
    
    # Get interesections
    intersections = poly.intersection()
    
    # IoU based upon intersection and sum of areas
    if intersections:
        area_intersection = Poly(intersections).area()
        result = area_intersection/(area1 + area2 - area_intersection)
    else:
        result = 0.0
        
    return result

print(polygon_iou(p1, p2))
```

*Test*

```
p1 = [  (-0.708, 0.707),
        (0.309, -0.951),
        (0.587, -0.809)]  

p2 = [  (1, 0),
        (0, 1),
        (-1, 0),
        (0, -1),
        (0.708, -0.708)]

print(polygon_iou(p1, p2))
# Output: 0.12403616470027277
```

**Monte Carlo Simulation**

- Generate random points in the min/max x and y range of the points
- Count the number of points in either polygon (i.e. union)
- Count the number of points in both polygon (i.e. intersection)
- Ratio of the number of points in the intersection to the number in the union is the answer

**Code**

```
import math
from random import uniform

def ray_tracing_method(x, y, poly):
    '''
       Determines if point x, y is inside polygon poly

       Source: "What's the fastest way of checking if a point is inside a polygon in python"
             at URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python

    '''
    n = len(poly)
    inside = False

    p1x,p1y = poly[0]
    for i in range(n+1):
        p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y,p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xints = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xints:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y

    return inside


def intersection_union(p1, p2, num_throws = 1000000):
    '''
        Computes the intersection untion for polygons p1, p2
        (assuming that p1, and p2 are inside at polygon of radius 1)
    '''
    # Range of values
    p = p1 + p2
    xmin = min(x[0] for x in p)
    xmax = max(x[0] for x in p)
    ymin = min(x[1] for x in p)
    ymax = max(x[1] for x in p)

    # Init counts
    in_union = 0
    in_intersect = 0
    throws = 0

    while (throws < num_throws):
        # Choose random x, y position in rectangle
        x_pos = uniform (xmin, xmax)
        y_pos = uniform (ymin, ymax)

        # Only test points inside unit circle
        # Check if points are inside p1 & p2
        in_p1 = ray_tracing_method(x_pos, y_pos, p1)
        in_p2 = ray_tracing_method(x_pos, y_pos, p2)

        if in_p1 or in_p2:
            in_union += 1             # in union

        if in_p1 and in_p2:
            in_intersect += 1         # in intersetion

        throws += 1   
        
    return in_intersect/in_union
        
print(intersection_union(p1, p2))
```

*Test*

```
p1 = [  (-0.708, 0.707),
        (0.309, -0.951),
        (0.587, -0.809)]  

p2 = [  (1, 0),
        (0, 1),
        (-1, 0),
        (0, -1),
        (0.708, -0.708)]

intersection_union(p1, p2)

# Out: 0.12418051627698147
```

Comment: @DarryIG Looks like these approaches won't detect if the polygons are not intersecting and are just sharing an edge? It throws an error

Comment: @NovelPomodoro--could you add an example of non-intersecting polygons to your question (in which case I assume the IoU should be zero)?

Comment: @DarryIG poly1 = [
        (0.540, -0.540),
        (1, 0),
        (-1, 0),
        (-0.540 -0.540)
    ]
    poly2 = [
        (1, 0),
        (0, 1),
        (-1, 0)]

Comment: @NovelPomodoro--updated RaffleBuffle approach wit the lines:  `pt_intersect = line_intersect(get_j, get_i); if pt_intersect: intersections.append(pt_intersect)` to fix issue with that approach.  The other two approaches didn't need any modification.  Does this work for you now?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming polygons are non self-intersecting, i.e. the ordering of the points around the circle is monotonic, then I believe there is a relatively simple way to determine the IoU value without requiring a general shape package.

1. Assume the points of each polygon are ordered clockwise around the circle. We can ensure this by sorting by increasing angle w.r.t the x-axis or reversing the points if we find the signed area is negative.
2. Combine points from both polygons into a single list, `L`, keeping track of which polygon each point belongs to. We also need to be able to determine the previous and next point in the original polygon for each point.
3. Sort `L` by increasing angle w.r.t the x-axis.
4. If the input polygons intersect the number of transitions from one polygon to the other while iterating through `L` will be greater than two.
5. Iterate through `L`. If successive points are encountered belonging to different polygons then the intersection of the lines between the 1st point and its next point and the 2nd point and its previous point will belong to the intersection  between the two polygons.
6. Add each point identified in step 4 to a new polygon, `I`. Points of `I` will be encountered in order.
7. The sum of the areas of each polygon will be equal to their union plus the area of the intersection, since this will be counted twice.
8. The value of `IoU` will therefore be given by the area of `I` divided by the sum of the areas of the two polygons minus the area of `I`.

The only geometry required is to calculate the area of a simple polygon using the [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula), and to determine the point of intersection between two line segments, required by step 5.

Here's some Java code ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/q6crQL)) to illustrate - you can probably make it a lot more compact in Python.

```
double[][] coords = {{-0.708, 0.707, 0.309, -0.951, 0.587, -0.809},
                       {1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0.708, -0.708}};

double areaSum = 0;
List<CPoint> pts = new ArrayList<>();
for(int p=0; p<coords.length; p++)
{
    List<CPoint> poly = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j=0; j<coords[p].length; j+=2)
    {
        poly.add(new CPoint(p, coords[p][j], coords[p][j+1]));
    }
    
    double area = area(poly);
    if(area < 0)
    {
        area = -area;
        Collections.reverse(poly);
    }
    areaSum += area;
    
    pts.addAll(poly);

    int n = poly.size();
    for(int i=0, j=n-1; i<n; j=i++)
    {
        poly.get(i).prev = poly.get(j);
        poly.get(j).next = poly.get(i);             
    }
}       
        
pts.sort((a, b) -> Double.compare(a.theta, b.theta));
        
List<Point2D> intersections = new ArrayList<>();
int n = pts.size();
for(int i=0, j=n-1; i<n; j=i++)
{
    if(pts.get(j).id != pts.get(i).id)
    {
        intersections.add(intersect(pts.get(j), pts.get(j).next, pts.get(i).prev, pts.get(i)));
    }
}

double areaInt = area(intersections);
double iou = areaInt/(areaSum - areaInt);
System.out.println(iou);
```

Output:

```
0.12403616470027268
```

And supporting code:

```
static class CPoint extends Point2D.Double
{
    int id;
    double theta;
    CPoint prev, next;
    
    public CPoint(int id, double x, double y)
    {
        super(x, y);
        this.id = id;
        theta = Math.atan2(y, x);
        if(theta < 0) theta = 2*Math.PI + theta;
    }
}   

static double area(List<? extends Point2D> poly)
{
    double area = 0;
    for(int i=0, j=poly.size()-1; i<poly.size(); j=i++)
        area += (poly.get(j).getX() * poly.get(i).getY()) - (poly.get(i).getX() * poly.get(j).getY());
    return Math.abs(area)/2;
}

// https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_the_intersection_of_two_lines#Java
static Point2D intersect(Point2D p1, Point2D p2, Point2D p3, Point2D p4)
{
  double a1 = p2.getY() - p1.getY();
  double b1 = p1.getX() - p2.getX();
  double c1 = a1 * p1.getX() + b1 * p1.getY();

  double a2 = p4.getY() - p3.getY();
  double b2 = p3.getX() - p4.getX();
  double c2 = a2 * p3.getX() + b2 * p3.getY();

  double delta = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;
  return new Point2D.Double((b2 * c1 - b1 * c2) / delta, (a1 * c2 - a2 * c1) / delta);    
}
```